# Golang worker pool implementation working unexpectedly

Tags: go, goroutine

I have implemented a golang worker pool as below where sem and work are channels. sem is a channel to keep track of number of workers(goroutines) currently active. work is channel to pass functions to active workers to execute. timeout will return any worker idle for the timeout duration.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

type Pool struct {
    sem chan struct{}
    work chan func()
    timeout time.Duration
}

func NewPool(max, size, spawn int, timeout time.Duration) *Pool {
    if spawn <= 0 {
        panic("workpool spawn is <= 0")
    }
    if spawn > max {
        panic("workpool spawn > max workers")
    }
    p := &Pool{
        sem: make(chan struct{}, max),
        work: make(chan func(), size),
        timeout: timeout,
    }
    for i := 0; i < spawn; i++ {
        p.sem <- struct{}{}
        go p.worker(func() {})
    }
    return p

}

func (p *Pool) AddTask(task func()) {
    select {
        case p.work <- task:
            return
        case p.sem <- struct{}{}:
            go p.worker(task)
            return
    }
}

func (p *Pool) worker(task func()) {
    t := time.NewTimer(p.timeout)
    defer func() {
        t.Stop()
        <- p.sem
    }()

    task()

    for {
        select {
            case task := <- p.work:
                t.Reset(p.timeout)
                task()
            case <- t.C:
                return
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing by printing the value of i in a for loop by passing it into the pool wrapped in an anonymous function as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world!")

    p := NewPool(3, 10, 1, time.Duration(5) * time.Second)

    for i:=0; i<30; i++ {
        p.AddTask(func () {
            fmt.Print(i, " ")
        })
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("End")

}
```

The expected output should be serial numbers from 0 to 29 but instead output is

```
Hello, world!
12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 25 30 30 30 30 End
```

I cannot understand why the output is like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function closures are all referencing the same value of `i`. This creates a race condition, as the functions are dispatched, they are reading a changing value - hence the unpredictable output you are seeing.

To ensure closure gets a unique value, declare the variable within the loop. A simple trick to do this is by shadow declaring the same variable name `i := i`

```
for i:=0; i<30; i++ {
    i:= i                // <- add this
    p.AddTask(func () {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    })
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/o0Nyx5A46tp

---

BTW this technique is covered in the [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#channels) docs, see this section:

> It may seem odd to write
>
> ```
> req := req
> ```
>
> but it's legal and idiomatic in Go to do this. You get a fresh version
> of the variable with the same name, deliberately shadowing the loop
> variable locally but unique to each goroutine.

Comment: Thank you so much, but in my case the variable i is passed without the & symbol so why the function closures are referencing to i, instead all functions should get a copy of variable i, right?

Comment: @ANKURKUMAR using &i would not help, since it will be the same address for each loop iteration, since the var `i` gets "recycled" (only the content changes, the address stays the same).

Comment: @ANKURKUMAR no, a function will only get a copy of a value if the value is passed as an argument - and passing `i` as a parameter here would also fix the bug.  The reason the closures can read (and write) without the pointer address is because  the `i` is from an outer scope. Think of a global variable: all functions have read/write access these as they are in an outer scope. The same concept applies here. The race condition in your case is all your closures reference the _same_ scoped variable.